# How to put a whole SQLite file in cache in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sqlite, asp.net-mvc-4

Noob needs help)
I'm having a trouble with caching an SQLite database in ASP.NET MVC 4. All I need is to create a temporary copy of `DB.db` file and use it within a session and delete it when the session is over. Without doing it one session can crash another while using the same databse file. 
Of course I could do something like

```
Cache["Database"] = //Some code transfering DB.db content to cache
```

but there must be some way to copy it for a while. `File.Copy()` and `File.Delete()` doesn't fit.

P.S.> Sorry, I'm completely bumb in using databases. On my way to exploring entity fw)

Answer (score 0):

You can create sqlite databases in memory, then I guess you could add that sqlite db to a session.  This seems like a real bad practice though.  I'd rethink what you are trying to do.  If you proceed this way google sqlite db memory...I think I remember you just add something on to the connection string to create the db in memory.